# Issues in widget preview layout adaptation in host application

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-12, resourcesnotfoundexception

Im currently working on Andorid 12, with min sdk version as 31 in both host and widget provider application. From AppWidgetProviderInfo, I got the layout id of previewLayout but I'm trying to display the same in host customisation screen. While trying to do the same I got ResourcesNotFoundException in host implementation.

I added the preview layout in my AppWidgetProviderInfo.xml

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_initial_layout"
    android:previewLayout="@layout/widget_preview_layout"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview_image"
    android:minWidth="130dp"
    android:minHeight="170dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen" />
```

My host adaptation of preview layout is,

```
Drawable previewDrawable = widgetInfo.getAppWidgetInfo().loadPreviewImage(binding.getRoot().getContext(), ICON_DENSITY);
int previewLayout = widgetInfo.getAppWidgetInfo().previewLayout;
   try {
      if (previewLayout != 0) {

         View widgetPreview = LayoutInflater.from(binding.getRoot().getContext()).inflate(previewLayout, binding.getRoot(), false);
         binding.widgetContainer.addView(widgetPreview);
       } else if (previewDrawable != null) {

            Glide.with(binding.getRoot().getContext())
                        .load(previewDrawable)
                        .into(binding.previewImage);
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With the above code, Im able to show the preview image from AppWidgetProviderInfo but while trying to inflate the previewLayout with layout id alone, I get ResourcesNotFoundException. In mycase the widgetprovider and Host are two different applications.